# How to set my UIButton tittle inside of uicollection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

so I want to set my button tittle like this with my array, but the result the button title didn't show my array

//viewcontroller

```
let menus = ["Topokki","Sundubu","Galbitang"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return menus.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell



    cell.menusButton.titleLabel?.text = menus[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
}
```

//collectionviewcell class

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var menusButton: UIButton!


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cell.menusButton.setTitle(menus[indexPath.item], forState: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs about [`titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel) of `UIButton`

> To set the actual text of the label, use `setTitle(_:for:)` (`button.titleLabel.text` does not let you set the text)

So... you need to set title of your button by calling `setTitle(_:for:)`

```
cell.menusButton.setTitle(menus[indexPath.item], for: .normal)
```